# flutter (rethrow) When I try to restart the program it takes me to image_provider.dart (rethrow)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

```
   Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        leftImageName = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'images/$leftImageName.png',
                    )),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        rightImageName = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Image.asset('images/$rightImageName.png')),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

When I try to restart the program it takes me to image_provider.dart (rethrow) why ???
Is it wrong with the code or is it something else?
And what is the meaning of rethrow
can someone help me please

Comment: Can you include the error message

Comment: I deleted everything and re-download it and the problem was solved. Thank you very much Mr. Yeasin for your initiative to help me

Answer (score 0):

#### There is nothig wrong with the code actually

- Make sure you provided the right path to your image.
- have you added these images to your assets in `pubspec.yaml` file ?
- are these images in the root of your project ? ( According to the path you passed to the widget, It means that all your images are in the root folder of your project, where your `pubspec.yaml` file is located!

###### Crosscheck your pubspec.yaml very well. The issue might be you have not specify the path to yout image files well.

Comment: I didn't know what the exact problem was, but I checked everything you mentioned and didn't see an error, so I deleted all the pictures and went back to downloading them and adding them to (pubspec.yaml), and when I restarted the application everything worked. Anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your pubspec.yaml has right file extension.

For eg:
If file name is logo.jpg, then use logo.jpg in pubspec.yaml as well as in dart file.

I had habituated to type logo.png so I had faced same error. Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34642949)